# Insert Records one by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, insert

I have three tables below.  I want to insert records into a CSV file by contract.  There are three tables with different column counts.  Contracts has 5 columns, Member has 3 columns, and QTY has 2 columns.  I have to insert the records by contract so the output in the CSV file will look like the output below.

```
select * from #contracts_master where ContractNumber='PCCCA7859'
select * from #Member_full where ContractNumber='PCCCA7859'
select * from #QTY where ContractNumber='PCCCA7859'
```

Output

```
Contract_Master_Record,Contract_1,Contract Pharmacy 3,11/1/2019,11/31/2019
Member_full_Record,Member_333,Rite_Aid
QTY_Record,Product_111
```

How can I create a csv extract where I insert one record by one like this?

Can I use BCP?

Comment: Import the entire CSV into a temporary staging table. From that point, you can do whatever you want with standard SQL.

Comment: I didn't understand well, but I think if you join your tables and save result as csv, with some changes to your file in excel, your problem may be solved

Answer (score 0):

You can export a table to a csv using BCP like this

```
bcp database_name.table_name out "c:\location\to\file.csv" -c -t, -T -S server_name
```

You can export the results of a query like this

```
bcp "select col1, col2 database_name.table_name" queryout "c:\location\to\file.csv" -c -t, -T -S server_name
```

I think what you're referring to when you say 'line by line' could be a reference to perhaps append data to a file as it becomes available? say if you're running a query on a schedule?

BCP doesn't have append but you could do something like this

```
bcp database_name.table_name out "c:\location\to\temp_file.csv" -c -t, -T -S server_name && type c:\location\to\temp_file.csv >> c:\location\to\final_file.csv
```

see http://mvark.blogspot.com/2009/09/appending-to-file-with-bcp.html